# I am trying to produce a LULC using supervised classification , but I got an out-put in gray color

Tags: google-earth-engine, values, palette

I am trying to produce a LULC using supervised classification , however, I am getting an output in gray color. Anyone knows what is the issue?

```js
    // Supervised Image Classification with Landsat 8 image 

var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')

var filtered=image.filterBounds(zone3)
             .filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-12-31')
             .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
             .select('B.*')
              
Map.addLayer(zone3,{bands:['B4','B3','B2']}, 'TrueColor')

Map.centerObject(zone3, 8);           

// 2. Set visualization parameter          

var before= filtered.median().clip(zone3);
Map.addLayer(before,imageVisParam, 'before');

//After 2020

var after1 = image.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(zone3))
              .filterDate('2015-01-01','2015-12-31')
              .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
              .select('B.*')
             
// 2. Set visualization parameter          

var after= after1.median().clip(zone3);
Map.addLayer(after,imageVisParam2, 'after');

//Training

var training = water.merge(prosopis).merge(barren).merge(bush).merge(builtin).merge(cropland).merge(grassland);

var bands= ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'];


//Extract the pixel values
var training1 = before.select(bands). sampleRegions({
  collection: training,
  properties:['class'],
  scale:30,
  //tileScale:1
});
  
print(training1);

//Classifier

var classifier=ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
  features:training1,
 classProperty:'class',
  inputProperties:bands
 });
 
 var Pallete=[
            '1472f2',//water_body
            'ff4809',//prosopis
            'f6f6ca',//barren
            'ffc82d',//bush
            '9dcaac',//builtin
            '6ec209',//cropland
            'c1b572',//grassland
            ];

var beforeclassified=before.select(bands).classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(beforeclassified,{'pallete':Pallete, min:1,max:7},'before classified');

var afterclassified=after.classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(afterclassified,{'pallete':Pallete, min:1,max:7},'after classified');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled palette. Correct it, and it won't be gray anymore.

```
var Pallete = [
  '1472f2', //water_body
  'ff4809', //prosopis
  'f6f6ca', //barren
  'ffc82d', //bush
  '9dcaac', //builtin
  '6ec209', //cropland
  'c1b572', //grassland
]

var beforeclassified = ee.Image.random().multiply(7)

Map.addLayer(beforeclassified, {
  palette: Pallete,
  min: 1,
  max: 7
}, 'before classified')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! You are right. It is working well now!